# Getting only sub in UserInfoEndpoint

Tags: wso2, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I am just following what is on the [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Basic+Client+Profile+with+Playground)

I've already populated the user's profile information but so far **I only get `sub`**. I want to get something same like in the guide:

```
{ 
   "sub":"admin",
   "email":"admin@wso2.com",
   "website":"https://wso2.com",
   "name":"admin",
   "family_name":"admin",
   "preferred_username":"admin",
   "given_name":"admin",
   "profile":"https://wso2.com",
   "country":"Sri Lanka"
}
```

**CONFIG**

Identity Server - AWS Cloud with Domain and SSL + Nginx Proxy

Sample Web App - local machine

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

- It is an open [bug](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4250). What
  is the workaround to get the other fields? Based on that jira, only
  the password grant is not fix, where to get the fix for code and
  impilict grant?
- I tried hosting the IS also **locally**, same results

Comment: Tried with IS 5.2.0 and i was able to get the user profile information using the authorization code grant. I was able to get sub claim plus other claims i set. Can you provide a screenshot of your SP configuration? specially the claim configuration.

Comment: Added some more details. Do I need to configure something in claims? I'm plainly following the [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Basic+Client+Profile+with+Playground)

Comment: yup you need to configure required claims in the Service Provider configuration

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve OIDC claim attributes to id_token or userinfo endpoint, the following steps needs to be done correctly(assuming you are working on IS 5.2.0).
1. Update relevant claims' Mapped Attribute with your underlying user store's matching attributes.
2. Update requested claims to Service provider [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider).
3. Update missing attributes in '/_system/config/oidc' for scope 'openid' (Configuration changes in IS 5.2.0 [[2]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release)).